Spring Integration - TracingContext Lost in WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler
This issue is an extension of the SO issue Spring Integration Restore ReactorContext into Imperative Processing
Any exception thrown after the WebFlux call via WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler is missing the Trace information.
Sample depicting the problem available at https://github.com/syedyusufh/simple-handle-reactive.git
This is what is happening.

WebFlux call completed, but there are business errors in
response.
Transformer tries to convert the response to Object and
then looks for any business errors, if so throws user defined for
the same.
This exception thrown first gets logged automatically
via WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler where context is lost
Then the exception is forwarded to application defined errorChannel, which creates a new traceId

Exception:
2m2024-06-24T20:27:02.445+04:00  INFO 1436 --- [   scheduling-1] [66799e5608c967d694f450b82077c38c-fadc3f15d16b6b11] c.i.sample.config.TracingConfig          : Request Headers: [Content-Type:"application/json", traceparent:"00-66799e5608c967d694f450b82077c38c-fadc3f15d16b6b11-00"]
2024-06-24T20:27:03.997+04:00  INFO 1436 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] [66799e5608c967d694f450b82077c38c-fadc3f15d16b6b11] c.i.sample.config.TracingConfig          : Response Headers: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*", Alt-Svc:"h3=":443"; ma=2592000", Content-Type:"application/json", Date:"Mon, 24 Jun 2024 16:27:05 GMT", Server:"Caddy", Vary:"Accept-Encoding", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked"]
2024-06-24T20:27:04.089+04:00 ERROR 1436 --- [oundedElastic-1] [                                                 ] .o.WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler : Failed to send async reply: org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder@5e1691b0


Would you mind to elaborate how that throw new RuntimeException("Induced"); is relevant to WebFlux?

Pls see my edits

OK. So, probably when we come up with the fix for: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/9259, this one should be covered since context won't be lost in the WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler any more.

Thanks Artem, any workarounds until then, pls?

Do not throw that exception back to WebFlux channel adapter's thread. Consider to handle it manually or via ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/handler-advice/classes.html#expression-advice


any workarounds until then, pls?

Do not throw that exception back to WebFlux channel adapter's thread. Consider to handle it manually or via ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/handler-advice/classes.html#expression-advice
